To lie in/within somebody
I would like to know which of these sentences is correct/the most appropriate:

the necessary resource lies within him.
the necessary resource lies in him.

The meaning I am looking for: I want to express the idea that the person has all the necessary resources in his possession from a spiritual point of view.
As far as I found out, both roughly translate to the appropriate meaning. But there may be a subtle shade which I cannot get yet ..

Note that it's "resource" (one 's').

I wouldn't say it like that at all. He already has the spiritual resources he needs. The lie thing doesn't work for me at all.

@Lambie How would you rather say it?

I just posted it. :)

@kaya3 What variety of English? In English/American and English/UK dictionaries, this word is marked as "usually plural". Sure, you can use it in singular, but pluralizing it is going to more easily convey the intended message here.  I would only use the singular form in a very specific situation, like if you're singling out one specific resource and are denoting just that one.

@Brandin I don't think there is any variety of English where "ressource" is spelled with a double s.

These mean the same thing, with no difference to tone or implication. Additionally, you could phrase it as "The necessary resource lies inside him." This would be another way of saying the same thing.
In general, choosing longer words often sounds more formal or more poetic, so if I were trying to sound particularly formal or spiritual, I might choose the word within since it is longer/less common than either in or inside. Of these, in sounds the least formal, but this is a minor difference and not a hard rule. Even using the least formal in would be appropriate in a formal business or political setting, for example.
